# Load external JavaScript files where A requires B being loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, load, external, appendchild

I have a use case where I have a JS file that is lazy loaded. During development this JS file would be a combination of File A and File B. However in production it should load File A then File B for separation. 
This works properly when adding them directly to the DOM with

```
for(int i =0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + urls[i] + "'></script>");
}
```

Even if FileB loads before FileA, it doesn't get evaluated first.

My code is as follows

```
createScript: function(url, id) {
    var m = this;
    // flag as loaded
    var myonload = function() {
        Logger.debug(formatMessage(Library.RESOURCES["load.success"], [this.src, id]), "core");
        this.library_loaded = true;
    };

    // log loading error
    var myonerror = function() {
        Logger.warn(formatMessage(Library.RESOURCES["load.failure"], [this.src, id]), "core");
    };

    //If currently being grabbed
    // || m.currentAsyc[ids[i]+"/async"]
    if (Library.findScript(url))
        return;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.library_loaded = false;

    // mozilla
    script.onload = myonload;
    script.onerror = myonerror;
    // ie
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == "complete" || this.readyState == "loaded") {
            setTimeout(myonload.bindAsEventListener(this), 10);
            this.onreadystatechange = null;
        }
    };

    script.src = url;
    m.head.appendChild(script);         

},
```

This results in the DOM having

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/FileA"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/FileB"></script>
```

But when FileB loads faster then FileA it tries to evaluate itself first. 
Is there any way to prevent this?

Further explanation

I am trying to implement a Sprockets like functionality into a legacy system.
When I would normally ask for '/dyn/path/to/FileA' it would have
//= require FileB at the top sending a respones of

```
document.write("<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/FileA"></script>");
document.write("<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/FileB"></script>");
```

This works great as it does the calls synchronously. 
In this situation, I have made an AJAX call to see what files the dynamic FileA requires (those would be FileA and FileB). This returns saying that we need to request FileA and FileB. The problem is I need a call back to confirm when both of those files are actually loaded as I have a wait function for other areas that need this code as well. They are currently waiting just for the /dyn/path/to/FileA to complete loading, however we now need them to wait for FileA and FileB to complete their loading as well.

Comment: No, you cannot prevent this. But why would do that anyway?

Comment: Will update at bottom of post

Comment: If you can't just combine them into one file, have a look at [AMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition)

Comment: Updated first post.
I can combine during production and it all works hunky dory, but I really want to be able to separate the code during development. The callback is required to let all other portions of JS that are waiting for the scripts to know that all of the required scripts are finished loading, not just the single one they thought they needed.

Edit: It says prototype.js is AMD which is what is being used.

Comment: You had asked why I would want to. 
I want to prevent it because if A does not load before B is evaluated it will error out.

Comment: Then you will need to put a wrapper function around B, which will get executed right away when A is already loaded or which will wait for the load event of the A script. That's just what AMD does :-)

Comment: I was thinking about that, however I would need someway that the wrapper function around B would be completely ignored if the two files were combined into a single files during production.

Comment: The condition "module A already available" (so don't wait to execute) will be enough for that. You really might have a look at an AMD library like http://requirejs.org/, they support all these things so you don't need write your own.

Comment: Thanks again Bergi, I had been looking at requireJS originally for this but gave up when it didn't meet my needs. I only later realized that I was trying to use requireJS like Sprockets instead of as an AMD only. I currently have $script for it but realize that requireJS would fit better. I will make this question as answered or if you would like, you can turn a comment of yours into a solution and I will mark it as my answer needed.